How do I use a for loop inside a method with an array parameter?
I want to start and preference that I am still new to this and learning. I'm trying to figure out how to use a for loop for this assignment. Hopefully I can get some help :)
This is the code.
package com.h2;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }

    public static int doubleTheNumber(int number) {
        return number * 2;
    }

    private static int add(int[] numbers) {
      int sum = 0;

    }
}

This is the task
"For the implementation of add() method, replace return -1; from the last task with the following. Create a variable called sum, and initialize its value to 0. Then, using a for loop over numbers (or using a while loop), add every item in the numbers array to the sum variable. Finally, return sum."

You surely received instructions before the assignment. Otherwise, start with the tutorial

You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

You can implement the method as follows:
private static int add(int[] numbers) {
    // "sum" is our counter variable
    int sum = 0;

    // We iterate over the "numbers" array and add each element of the array to the counter "sum"
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }

    // Since we start from 0 (sum = 0), the result will be the sum of all the elements of "number" array
    return sum;
}


A for-each loop can simplify your code by a lot.
private static int add(int[] numbers) {
    int sum = 0;
    
    // For each number in the array numbers
    for(int number : numbers) 

        // Add sum by number
        sum += number;

    return sum;
}

However if your assignment suggest you use a for loop
// Start at index 0
// Loop while the value of i is less than the amounts of numbers in the array
// Increment i by 1 after each loop

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 

        // Add the number in index i of numbers to sum
        sum += numbers[i];

